# Grass preparation (base)

Tags: soil, grass, landscaping

I need advice on preparing my garden for planting grass seeds, I have a new build property and the current grass is always waterlogged. I plan on hiring a man with digger and removing the top 6-8 inch firstly is this enough? Secondly what base would you recommend to stop this again? I have conflicting advice, just soil or some sharp sand first then soil? I'm baffled. What quantity (depth) of each? Many thanks in advance

Comment: It might not be so simple- if its waterlogged, why is it waterlogged? Is the area lower than surrounding areas? Is there debris beneath the existing lawn? Does the lie of the land mean water ends up in your garden from everyone else's? Does it need drainage installing are questions that need answering... photos might help

Comment: Bamboo is right, we gotta figure out what the problem is to be able to help you.  Drainage is so very critical...and not that tough to fix.  Forget spending any money on quick fixes.  There is no 'base' that would mitigate very poor drainage.  Look at your property, who is higher than yours?  Who is lower?  Do you have an 'as-built' that normally comes with your mortgage papers?  Sometimes there are contours, elevations and hopefully all underground utilities shown on this as-built...and photos will help!

Comment: what part of the world do you live in and a plan or pictures would help too

Comment: Garden is on a slight slope around 6in drop over 9m or so, surrounded by a neighbours house at top, brick garage to left and brick wall to right. The house was built on former farm land. Not sure about as built info, I know I have waste manhole cover but nothing as as I'm aware. Will try and upload photo tried yesterday but wouldn't load.. thanks live in nottingham

Comment: Nottingham USA or UK?

Comment: Nottingham uk, didn't relise there was a nottingham USA